# Stripe error: EventEmitter is not a constructor

Tags: stripe-payments, svelte, vite, sveltekit

## Hello,

I'm working on project that use Stripe for payments, framework this project uses is SvelteKit and for convenience I also use TS.

I implemented Stripe payments, tested locally, everything worked fine, then I deployed project to Firebase cloud functions and then 1st error showed up. Endpoint for creating payment intents failed every time I called it (but only in FB cloud function, it never failed locally).

So I decided (not just because of this bug) to move function for generating payment intents to one of my __layout.svelte, where it can be called from front-end and executed on back-end without need to make HTTP request to endpoint that is exposed to whole internet.

### Stripe config:

```
import Stripe from "stripe";

console.log('secret defined:', import.meta.env.VITE_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
const stripe = new Stripe(import.meta.env.VITE_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
    apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
});
console.log('after stripe conf');

export default stripe;
```

I moved that function to desired __layout.svelte and got error `EventEmitter is not a constructor`.

Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69717406/typeerror-eventemitter-is-not-a-constructor-at-new-mapboxgeocoder) question, and did what answer advised. Then I got different error:
`http.Agent is not a constructor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is quite difficult problem, it is related to Vite. Stripe API for back-end is written in CJS and Vite has problems with processing CJS code when using SSR. According to docs I should include stripe for optimization, but that didn't work. These Github issues better describe this problem: [Svelte issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/928) [Vite issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2579).

I'm lucky enough that I use Firebase, so I fixed this by moving function for generating payment intents to Cloud Functions. So this is solution for me, and not for everyone, but I hope this will help someone.

Comment: Hi, you could test what I explained in this answer, I will be back with a result later as I need to implement Stripe on a Svelte app : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70478728/typeerror-crypto-createcipheriv-is-not-a-function/70479882#70479882

Comment: @flydev App you are talking about is Svelte or SvelteKit app?

Comment: @Hejmus the linked answer work is for Svelte, but the trick should also work for Sveltekit, if you want to try, you have to write the `imports` on `onMount()`. You can also ask a new question and ping me, I will see if I can sort out.